# How to sum up the value inside the loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, sum

Below is my code, I wonder how can I add up all the price after the loop break. As you can see, it will loop until the input is invalid. Every combo has a different price, if I order 3 different combo will be different price. What's the code so that I can sum up all the price?

```
combo = str(input('Enter Combo Type (A/B/C or X to end) ='))

while combo != 'x' and 'X':

    if combo == 'a' and 'A':
        qtt = int(input('How many do you want to order  ='))
        price = qtt * 40
        print('Order price for combo A =', price)
        combo = str(input('Enter Combo Type (A/B/C or X to end) ='))

    elif combo == 'b' and 'B':
        qtt = int(input('How many do you want to order  ='))
        price = qtt * 52
        print('Order price for combo B =', price)
        combo = str(input('Enter Combo Type (A/B/C or X to end) ='))

    elif combo == 'c' and 'C':
        qtt = int(input('How many do you want to order  ='))
        price = qtt * 46
        print('Order price for combo C =', price)
        combo = str(input('Enter Combo Type (A/B/C or X to end) ='))

    elif combo == 'x' and 'X':
        break

    else:
        print("Wrong input, please try again.")
```

Comment: `... == ... and ...` doesn't do what you think it does. Try `combo == 'a' or combo == 'A'` or `combo in {'a', 'A'}` or `combo.lower() == 'a'` for example.

Comment: In the sample, the 'and' clause is useless. You can cumulate all  single price in a tot_prices using +=. At the end tot_prices is your value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a running total of the price of each selection and print it at the end.

Some other notes on this code:

1. You can avoid repeating the `input` line by having it at the start of the loop.  A pretty standard pattern for this kind of repeating prompt is to loop on `while True`, get the input, and `break` when it matches the terminating condition.
2. You can avoid repeating the price calculation by putting the price for each combo in a dict.
3. Comparing against multiple values with `if combo = 'a' and 'A'` doesn't work -- it's simpler to just `.upper()` the value to force it to uppercase, and compare against that.

```
total = 0
prices = {
    'A': 40,
    'B': 52,
    'C': 46,
}

while True:
    combo = input('Enter Combo Type (A/B/C or X to end) =').upper()
    if combo == 'X':
        break
    if combo not in prices:
        print("Wrong input, please try again.")
        continue

    price = int(input('How many do you want to order  =')) * prices[combo]
    print(f'Order price for combo {combo} = {price}')
    total += price

print(f'Total: {total}')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can keep counts of each response. For example:

```
count = {'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':0}

qtt = int(input('How many of A do you want to order = '))
count['a'] += qtt
```

Once you exit the loop:

```
total = count['a'] * 40 + count['b'] * 52 + count['c'] * 46
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to append your total prices to a list and then sum it at the end.

Couple things about your code:

1. Don't use conditions like `if combo == "x" and "X"`, you should use either `if combo == "x" or combo == "X"`, or more simply, use `if combo in ('x', 'X')` if you need to check if something could be multiple values.
2. re: conditions, you could consider checking `combo.lower()`, i.e. `if combo.lower() == "x"` rather than checking multiple characters. You can even call `.lower()` or `.upper()` at the `input` call, i.e. `combo = str(input("Prompt:")).lower()`
3. You can simplify your code while putting the `combo` input call at the top of your while loop, then checking your conditions. Same with your price and qty inputs--write one print statement that loads the inputs you've already set. This will shorten and clean up your code considerably.
4. Now is a great time to look into f-strings rather than concatenation. With f-strings, you can write things like: `f'Order price for combo {combo} = {str(price)}'` rather than mucking around with + signs

   ```
   combo = None
   combo_list = []

   while combo != 'x':
       combo = str(input('Enter Combo Type (A/B/C or X to end) = ')).lower()
       if combo == 'x':
           break

       qtt = int(input('How many do you want to order = '))
       if combo == 'a':
           price = qtt * 40
       elif combo == 'b':
           price = qtt * 52
       elif combo == 'c':
           price = qtt * 46
       else:
           print("Wrong input, please try again.")

       combo_list.append(price)
       print(f'Order price for combo {combo} = {str(price)}')

   print(f'Total price = {str(sum(combo_list))}')
   ```